# How to run PowerShell script elegant?

Tags: powershell, simplify

For running **ps1** file I should type something like:

```
powershell "./script.ps1 -t 'Param string'"
```

But the running of **bat**-file has much more kindly view:

```
script 'Param string'
```

Is it possible to simplify the syntax to run a **ps1** file? It should be comfortable for typing from keyboard.

Comment: Where do you want to run the script from? PowerShell? cmd?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are tagged the question with `PowerShell` only, I assume you want to call a `ps1` from Powershell.

Consider a script printing a message, called message.ps1:

```
Param
(
    $msg
)

Write-Host $msg
```

The way I used to call it is:

```
.\message.ps1 -msg "hello"
```

You can also omit the `-msg` prefix and just pass the string to print:

```
.\message.ps1 "hello"
```

Comment: 1) Should I omit 'powershell' word if I run the script anywhere from the PC?
2) How could I omit ".\" characters?
3) How could I omit ".ps1" characters?

Comment: yes, omit PowerShell if you run the script inside powershell. If you wan't to make a function that is available in your session go read about PowerShell modules and / or PowerShell profile

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most easy way to solve my question is calling ps1 script from bat script.
Then the string `powershell "./script.ps1 -t 'Param string'"`
could be easy represented as `script 'Param string'`